# visual studio 2010 installation problem

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to install visual studio 2010.
but at the begining of installation I get this error message box:

" setup.exe has stopped working 
A problem coused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available."

and I can just click the button " close program"!

the version of my Windows is seven ultimate x86.

can anybody help me ?

Comment: Disconnect from the Internet, disable virus checkers (and other anti-malware software), make sure the Windows Installer service is running.

Comment: Make sure to run the setup program with administrative privileges, if you weren't already doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a running msiexec on your system.  Slay it and try again.

Comment: yes, the problem was (maybe) related to msiexec, I couldn't to slay it, then I load system in safe mode and try to find it. but I didn't found it. then I run setup.exe: everything was correct. thanks alot